# Test class is not full coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

Here is my apex class and Test class:

Some of lines are not covered in the class, i'l mentioned **--------** like this.
Apex Class:

```
public with sharing class TaskController {
   private ApexPages.StandardController sc;
   public String projectid{get;set;}
   public String subprjid{get;set;}
   public String mrkId{get;set;}
   Public Task Task{get;set;}
   public List<Members__c> mbrs;
   public Map<Id,Members__c> mbrsMap;
   private Marketing_activity__c ma = new Marketing_activity__c();
   private Project__c prj = new Project__c ();
   private Subproject__c sp = new Subproject__c ();
   public string contenttype{get;set;} 
   public TaskController (ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
       this.sc = sc;
       mbrs = new List<Members__c>();
       mbrsMap = new Map<Id,Members__c>();
       projectid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('planid');                     
       subprjid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('subid');
       mrkId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('mrkid');

        string mainStr = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('retURL');

       /* if(mainStr<>null){            
            List<String> str = mainStr.split('%');
            List<String> st = str[0].split('=');
            mrkId = st[0];           
        } */

       **if(mrkId<>null){
           Task= new Task(WhatId= mrkId);
           ma = [select Id,Owner.Id from Marketing_activity__c where Id  =:mrkId];
           mbrs = [select Id,ProjUsers__c from Members__c where Marketingmebers__c =:mrkId]; 
           if(!mbrs.isEmpty()){
               for(Members__c m : mbrs){
                   mbrsMap.put(m.ProjUsers__c,m);**   
               }
           }
       }
       else if(projectid<>null){ 
           **Task= new Task(WhatId= projectid);
           prj = [select Id, Owner.Id from Project__c  where Id  =:projectid];
           mbrs = [select Id,ProjUsers__c from Members__c where ProjMembers__c =:projectid];
           if(!mbrs.isEmpty()){
               for(Members__c m : mbrs){
                   mbrsMap.put(m.ProjUsers__c,m);**   
               }
           }
       }
       else if(subprjid<>null) {
           **Task= new Task(WhatId= subprjid);
           sp = [select Id, Owner.Id from Subproject__c where Id  =:subprjid];
           mbrs = [select Id,ProjUsers__c from Members__c where SubProjMembers__c =:subprjid];
           if(!mbrs.isEmpty()){
               for(Members__c m : mbrs){
                   mbrsMap.put(m.ProjUsers__c,m);**   
               }
           }
       }

   }

   Public PageReference Save(){

        insert Task;
        User u = [select Id from user where id=:userinfo.getuserid()];
        //Attachment Code
        attachment.OwnerId = task.OwnerId;
        attachment.ParentId = task.Id; // the record the file is attached to
        //attachment.OwnerId = u.id;
        attachment.ContentType=contentType;

        try {

            **if(mbrsMap.keySet().size()>0){
                if(!mbrsMap.containsKey(Task.OwnerID)){
                     system.debug('----No Member=----');
                     Members__c Mem = New Members__c();                                        
                     Mem.Role__c = 'Viewer';

                     if(mrkId<>null){
                         Mem.Marketingmebers__c= mrkId;   
                         //Mem.ProjUsers__c  = ma.owner.id;   
                         Mem.ProjUsers__c  = task.OwnerId;   
                     }
                     if(projectid<>null){
                         Mem.ProjMembers__c = projectid;
                         //Mem.ProjUsers__c  = prj.owner.id; 
                         Mem.ProjUsers__c  = task.OwnerId;
                     }
                     else if(subprjid<>null){
                         Mem.SubProjMembers__c = subprjid;
                         //Mem.ProjUsers__c  = sp.owner.id; 
                         Mem.ProjUsers__c  = task.OwnerId;
                     }  

                     insert mem;**      
                }
            }
            if(attachment.body<>null){
                   **insert attachment;**                   
             }
             Pagereference PR;                   
             if(mrkId<>null){
                 **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/Marketingactivity?id='+mrkId+'&sfdc.override=1');**
             }
             if(projectid<>null){
                 **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+projectid+'&sfdc.override=1');**
             }
             else if(subprjid<>null){
                 **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/SubProject?id='+subprjid+'&sfdc.override=1');**
             } 
             System.debug('===Page==='+pr);       
             return PR;  
         }
         catch(Exception ex){
             System.debug('===Exception Occured ==='+ex.getMessage());
             **ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error,'Duplicate User For Member'); 
             return null;**      
         }


   }
   public Attachment attachment {
      get {
          if (attachment == null)
            attachment = new Attachment();
          return attachment;
        }
      set;
    }  
     Public Pagereference cancel(){

         Pagereference PR;

         if(mrkId<>null){
                   **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/Marketingactivity?id='+mrkId+'&sfdc.override=1');**
               }

        else  if(subprjid<>null){

                   **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/SubProject?id='+subprjid+'&sfdc.override=1');**
                        }
         else  if(projectid<>null){
                    **PR = new Pagereference('/apex/ProjectDetails?id='+projectid+'&sfdc.override=1');**

           }

           return PR;
       }
       public String getRedirectToTemplate() {
           return null;
       }
       public Task templateInfo {get; set;}


      public Pagereference redirectToTemplate() {
          try{
          insert templateInfo;
          System.debug('----------------- templateInfo.Id :----------- ' + templateInfo.Id);
          }catch(Exception e){
              ApexPages.addMessages(e);
          }
          return null;
       }
}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
    public class TaskControllerTest{
           static testMethod void TaskController(){

           Profile p=[SELECT Id From Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
           User u2 =new User( Alias = 'newUser1' ,
           Email ='newuser123@testorg.com',
           EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
           LastName = 'Testing',
           LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
           LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
           UserName='newuser123@testorg.com',
           ProfileId=p.Id,
           TimeZoneSidKey    = 'America/Los_Angeles');
            insert u2;

            Project__c objproject = new Project__c ();
            objproject.Name='test';
           //objproject.Project_type__c='test';
            objproject.Starts_date__c= System.now().date();
            objproject.Ends_date__c= System.now().date();
            System.assertEquals('test', objproject.name);
            insert objproject;

            Subproject__c objsp = new Subproject__c ();
            objsp.name = 'testname';
            objsp.Description__c = 'sampdesc';
            objsp.Starts_date__c = date.today();
            objsp.Ends_date__c = date.today();
            //objsp.Project_del__c = ;
            //objsp.Parent_project__c = 'pproj';
            //objsp.Project_type__c = 'prtyp';
            objsp.Status__c = 'Notstarted';
            //objsp.StatusImage__c = 'Inprograss';
            //objsp.user__c = u2.id;        
            System.assertEquals('testname', objsp .name);
            insert objsp ; 


            Marketing_activity__c objMarketingact=new Marketing_activity__c();
            objMarketingact.Name='test';
            objMarketingact.Description__c='tdescriptionest';
            objMarketingact.Status__c='completed';
            System.assertEquals('test', objMarketingact.name);
            insert objMarketingact;

            Task objtask = new Task();      
            objtask.Task_name__c = 'testname';
            objtask.WhatId=objproject.id;                      
            System.assertEquals('testname', objtask .Task_name__c); 
            //insert objtask ;

             Members__c objmember=new Members__c ();
            //objmember.Name ='test';
            //objmember.ProjMembers__c='test';
            //objmember.ProjUsers__c=u2.Id;
           //objmember.SubProjMembers__c='test';
            objmember.Role__c='Member';
            objmember.User_Email__c ='standarduser1@test.com';
            System.assertEquals('Member', objmember.Role__c);
            insert objmember;

            /*Task objtask1 = new Task();      
            objtask1.Task_name__c = 'testname';
            objtask1.WhatId=objsp.id;                      
            System.assertEquals('testname', objtask1.Task_name__c); 
            //insert objtask ;
            Task objtask2 = new Task();      
            objtask2.Task_name__c = 'testname';
            objtask2.WhatId=objMarketingact.id;                      
            System.assertEquals('testname', objtask2.Task_name__c); 
            //insert objtask ;*/

            ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', objtask.id);
            PageReference pageRef = Page.Purchaseorderpage;
            Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 
            ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(objtask);
            test.starttest();
            TaskController tsk = new TaskController(sc);
            tsk.Task = objtask;
            tsk.Save();
            tsk.cancel();
            tsk.getRedirectToTemplate();
            tsk.redirectToTemplate();
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: Could not get your question exactly. Can you please explain what is your exact problem that you are facing.

Comment: in my test class i didn't cover page reference methods and some if-else methods.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? You've told us that some lines are not covered, but what have you done to try and cover them?

Comment: @NitishSinghal I've converted your valid comment from answer to a comment. It's appropriate to use comments to ask for clarification. As soon as you reach 50 reputation you'll be able to comment everywhere.

Comment: for above test class i get only 30% code coverage. so any body help me how to increase the code coverage???????

Comment: When i run the above test class, i'l get 30% coverage and some lines in apex class are not covered. i'l indicate that lines with ** this type.                          so pls any body help me how to cover those lines and increase the code coverage.

Comment: can i add any code in test class. pls suggest me....

Comment: @fsales572 which line that not covered?Is it start with **

Answer (score 1):

This platform is not ment to write test code for you. But if you are willing to put some effort in it, you could perform the following steps in order to increase the code coverage **and** assert the correct behavior of your code:

1. You need at least one testmethod per public method and separate testmethods for each if-condition and each try/catch block. It is often necessary to also test private methods, because it is hard to reach them by only testing your public methods.
2. Setup your test data in each testmethod in a way to reach the desired lines of code.
3. Call the code under test with the tailored test data.
4. Assert, that the behavior of the executed code has been correct by checking its return values or changes at the database.